# Why activating Jupyter with xeus-cling fails

Tags: jupyter-notebook, xeus-cling

I am trying to activate Jupiter with xeus-cling C++ kernel on windows 10
I did the following:

- Installed a brand new Miniconda
- Created a new environment
- Installed Jupyter (unisng conda install)
- Installed xeus-cling using the command :

  conda install xeus-cling notebook -c QuantStack -c conda-forge
- I activated the Jupyter notebook and got the following kernel error

```html
[I 22:30:00.589 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\IlanH
[I 22:30:00.589 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 22:30:00.605 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8cb940353f781842ede9d93e3489b7d108179ad11837e49e
[I 22:30:00.605 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 22:30:00.855 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/IlanH/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-13328-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=8cb940353f781842ede9d93e3489b7d108179ad11837e49e
[I 22:30:16.874 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 22:30:21.022 NotebookApp] Kernel started: bd4fa5d4-5007-4f70-b7bb-bf8eca013c99
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
ERROR in cling::CIFactory::createCI():
  resource directory C:/bld/xeus-cling_1544660831115/_b_env/Library\lib\clang\5.0.0 not found!
input_line_1:1:10: fatal error: 'new' file not found
#include <new>
         ^~~~~
Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():
  Possible C++ standard library mismatch, compiled with _CRT_MSVCP_CURRENT 'msvcp140.dll'
  Extraction of runtime standard library version was: ''
[I 22:30:29.949 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
2
2
```

```
[I 22:30:00.589 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\IlanH
[I 22:30:00.589 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 22:30:00.605 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8cb940353f781842ede9d93e3489b7d108179ad11837e49e
[I 22:30:00.605 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 22:30:00.855 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/IlanH/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-13328-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=8cb940353f781842ede9d93e3489b7d108179ad11837e49e
[I 22:30:16.874 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 22:30:21.022 NotebookApp] Kernel started: bd4fa5d4-5007-4f70-b7bb-bf8eca013c99
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
ERROR in cling::CIFactory::createCI():
  resource directory C:/bld/xeus-cling_1544660831115/_b_env/Library\lib\clang\5.0.0 not found!
input_line_1:1:10: fatal error: 'new' file not found
#include <new>
         ^~~~~
Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():
  Possible C++ standard library mismatch, compiled with _CRT_MSVCP_CURRENT 'msvcp140.dll'
  Extraction of runtime standard library version was: ''
[I 22:30:29.949 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
2
2
```

What can I do to solve the problem ?
Ilan

Comment: Same problem here :)

Answer (score 1):

Afraid its just a matter of support. Windows is not yet supported... you will have to use  linux or OS X for now.